# How to configure OpenEMPI to subscribe HIEOS XDS.b registry as PIX Consumer

Tags: xml, configuration, mpi

I am trying to subscribe HIEOS XDS.b registry v1.2 as a PIX Consumer to OpenEMPI v2.2.7. I would appreciate a detailed explanation or a link to a resource. I tried to modify IheActors.xml, PixConsumerConnections.xml and PixPdqClientDomains.xml to configure it, but no luck so far.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed OpenEMPI to send messages to HIEOS by modifying pixV3ConsumerConnection and also adding these two properties   (I am not completely sure if these are really required or not, but I had those when I succeeded. Also, I don't know if I broke something when I modified pixV3ConsumerConnection, I didn't try adding a new connection at the time of my last attempt).

I also want to mention that I had to deploy OpenEMPI on Tomcat6 to use this feature, I realized that I was getting an exception on JBoss 4.2.3.GA. I googled it and I believe that is an issue specific to that JBoss version. Additionally, when you are testing this you should send a PIX Add message using SoapUI or some other Soap client, if you add patients from the admin console of OpenEMPI, I think this push-based notification code is skipped (but you can still use the pull-based notifications when you add patients from admin console, but you need to make sure that the brokerService and notificationBroker are initialized properly in applicationContext-service.xml and you have proper admin-configuration element with update-notification-entry in mpi-config.xml).

By the way, after accomplishing the push of the global patient id from OpenEMPI to HIEOS, I saw that HIEOS doesn't do anything unless it is already added to XDS.b Registry. I mean, if you send a PIX Add message to OpenEMPI, it sends out an update message to HIEOS, but HIEOS returns "patient id does not exist-skipping UPDATE" message. I will spend more time with the specs to understand this logic.

[The related post on OpenEMPI Forum](https://kenai.com/projects/openempi/forums/developer-forum/topics/532861-Configure-OpenEMPI-to-feed-HIEOS-XDS-b-registry-with-global-patient-id)
[The related post on HIEOS Forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/hieos/discussion/1085165/thread/6edccd17/)